# Program won't call correct function based on input. No idea what I'm missing

Tags: function, input, module, call

EDIT: After playing around a bit in main(), it seems like the program is choosing whichever function is being called in the if/elif block regardless of input. I have no idea why it started doing this after working fine

I've gone over and over my code, and I can't figure out what I'm not seeing.
It's a number sequence game, and it asks the user to choose a difficulty between easy and hard. It was working just fine at one point, but now no matter what is selected, it goes to easy mode each time. Even you hit enter without any input at all.

```
#main program function and difficulty selection
def main():
print('-----------------------------------------------')
print('Please choose a difficulty.')
difficulty = str(input('(e)asy|(h)ard: '))
print('-----------------------------------------------')
if difficulty == 'easy'or'e':
     easy()
elif difficulty == 'hard'or'h':
     hard()
```

Then I have a function for easy and one for hard.
Hard is just the easy function, with only a change to the size of the sequence generated and nothing else. I've gone over each block and nothing is changed that would affect which function is called.

It happens regardless of how many times the game is played, so it has to be something wrong with my main() function

The rest of the code is here if that helps, maybe I'm missing something obvious.

```
import random
def easy():
    print ('Easy Mode','\n')
  #Generates inital number, step value, and upper limit
    num_sequence = 5
    numbers = random.randint(1,101)
    step = random.randint(1,20)
  #Accumulates and prints all but last number in sequence
    for num_generated in range (1, num_sequence):
        print(numbers)
        numbers = numbers + step
  #Sets tries allowed and subtracts wrong attempts
    guesses = 3
    while guesses > 0:
        user_num = int(input('Next Number: '))
        guesses = guesses - 1
        if user_num != numbers:
            if guesses == 0:
                break
            else:
                print('Try Again (Attempts Remaining:', guesses,')')              
        if user_num == numbers:
            break

#Prints appropriate message based on game results                      
  if user_num == numbers:
      print ('Correct','\n')
  if user_num != numbers:
       print ('Attempts Exceeded: The answer was',numbers,'\n')

#block for hard difficulty (same as above, sequence size changed to 4)
def hard():
    print ('Hard Mode','\n')
    num_sequence = 4

#main program function and difficulty selection
def main():
    print('-----------------------------------------------')
    print('Please choose a difficulty.')
    difficulty = str(input('(e)asy|(h)ard: '))
    print('-----------------------------------------------')
    if difficulty == 'easy'or'e':
         easy()
    elif difficulty == 'hard'or'h':
         hard()

#block for replay selection
replay = 'y'
while replay == 'y':
    main()
    replay = input('Play again? (y)|(n): ',)
    print ('\n')
    if replay == 'n':
        print('-----------------------------------------------')
        print('Goodbye!')
        print('-----------------------------------------------')
        break
```

hard() is the same code as easy() line for line after those first few

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are making a compound comparison (using the or) both sides of the condition must be complete. In other words,

```
if difficulty == 'easy'or difficulty == 'e':
    easy()
elif difficulty == 'hard'or difficulty == 'h':
    hard()
```

Otherwise you are saying "if difficulty == 'easy' >> which is false, then assign difficulty to 'e'" which was not the intent.

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much. That's what I get for trying to be fancy.

Comment: Well GET FANCY!! Because that's how we learn! Nice program btw!

Comment: Thank you. Mind if I ask what I've done right with it? We're only 6 weeks into class, so I'm still pretty new at programming all together.